# How does one view pictures fullscreen on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

There is an annoyance in the iPhone 5 that the camera sensor is 4:3 but the phone display is 16:9. This makes photos not cover the entire screen.

Apple has now begun running a Thanksgiving commercial where they show the person viewing their photos and it takes up the whole screen of the phone.

Is there some setting configuration that I can change to display pictures fullscreen?

You can see the commercial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xHquhlr45w).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double tap on the photo to make it full screen. Alternatively, you can see toward the end of the commercial, a simple swipe to the left or the right brings up subsequent photos full screen without the overlay of controls on the top or bottom.

Comment: I also think there is a 5 second timer so if you pull up a picture to show someone else, the upper and lower overlays will fade out after being shown for a few seconds initially.

Comment: Yeah, that’s true. It doesn’t come back if you change the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I am certainly no expert here but what I do after taking a picture I go back and view it of corse. If I want to make it full screen I zoom in or stretch it only enough to fill the whole screen. I center it the way I want and then I simply take a screen shot by pressing the home key and off button at the same time. When you pull the screen shot back up it will be full screen. You will lose a slight amount picture quality or resalotion and it also seems to take a little longer to send it by text or email but for me its worth the trade off. You can basicly do the same thing by editing and cropping with a 16:9 aspect ratio. You would think with modern technology they could at least give us that option to do that and not loose any picture quality. I Hope that will help some of you and also hope to learn a better way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Tap the picture once.  This hides the top and bottom menu bars.

Answer (score -2):

Take a picture, stretch it to the size you want, when it fits nicely, take a picture of the screen by pushing the home key and on off button at the same time. Your photo will be put in your photos full screen... It is simple, you can do it!